# How to get access to hidden folders from another Macintosh HD (Users/Applications)?

Tags: finder, hard-drive, backup, startup, permission

I need to back up the main Users folder, as well as all other data, from my main Mac (2013 13" MBP). I've gotten the dreaded UEFI-inspired flashing question mark, and tried running Disk Utility's repair options on it, both on in recovery mode on the main machine, as well as from another machine (with the drive connected via a SATA-to-USB cable into another older MBP — my wife's).

B/c I didn't have the option of backing up the machine "normally" — copying all files and folders through the Finder of my wife's machine, due to perms issues — I've used the utility app Disk Drill to create a `.dmg` file, encompassing the whole drive's contents (a byte-for-byte copy, is what it's called in this software).

First, is there any other way of getting to the main Users folder, and the Applications, too? They're all hidden, as they were installed/created by a user not present on my wife's machine? (I just wanted the assurance of copying the files by hand, too, before wiping my machine's 1TB SSD and restoring the files from the disk image file I'd created in Disk Drill.) Secondarily (as a bonus question), is there anything suspect with the above approach?

*Many, **many** thanks*, to all who take the time to read, much less answer.

Comment: You mean literally hidden, as in they will appear if you toggle Cmd/shift/. or do you mean 'restricted' with a no-entry sign?

Comment: @Tetsujin No, tried this, and actually, I can see all the UNIX-y stuff (`var`, `bin`, `dev`, `opt`, etc.) when looking at the externally-connected Macintosh HD from my wife's computer, but when I go _into_ the `Users` folder, and then hit Command + Shift + `.` I still only see `Shared`. Same with `Applications` and `Library`… how can I remedy this? Also, is the fact that I can't see them now mean that a restore made from a disk image of this drive will still be, well, borked? (I guess the answer to your above question is "Neither!")

Comment: If you *literally* do to see the user's folder that you need, then the crash may have damaged the logical structure of the disk. And with APFS disks the number of data recovery/repair utilities for macOS are thin on the ground. A byte by byte copy *may* have gotten all of her data, but I'm an "I'll believe it when I see it" kind of guy so tread cautiously on the original source drive. You don't want to make it worse than it already is.

Comment: 1. Are you on Catalina or Big Sur? If so, are you sure you’re looking at the **Data** volume (e.g., “*Macintosh HD - Data*” rather than the **System** volume (e.g. “*Macintosh HD*”)? 2. For completeness, could you provide the outputs of `$ mount` and `$ ls -la /path/to/Users`?

Comment: @SteveChambers That's what I'm afraid of. While it's more expensive, I might have to go the route of buying a **_new_** SSD, and then restoring to it in a number of ways, seeing what shakes out. BTW, how does the partitioning scheme being APFS make things "thin" when it comes to options?

Comment: @pion Hey, so… the crashed computer/drive is on Catalina, but b/c my wife's computer is that much older… it's on High Sierra. Is there any issue using a High Sierra computer to view drive info, given this, BTW? (Getting USB A-to-C adapters this morning, so I can use my work machine, a 2018 MBP running Catalina currently, to view the drive instead, so if I need a Catalina machine, I'll have access to it shortly — 1–3 hrs.) Getting the `mount` and `ls -la` output shortly. (Thanks so much for your time, BTW!)

Comment: @pion OK, so... `mount`:

`/dev/disk4s5 on /Volumes/Macintosh HD 1 (apfs, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, journaled, noowners)`

And `ls -la /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ 1/Users/`:

`total 0` /
`drwxr-xr-x@  3 ashleyannette  staff   96 Oct 12  2019 .` /
`drwxr-xr-x  22 ashleyannette  staff  704 Oct 19 00:28 ..` /
`drwxrwxrwt   2 ashleyannette  staff   64 Aug 24  2019 Shared`
```

Comment: APFS is new(ish) and many of the go to repair utilities don’t work with APFS yet. Hence “thin.”

Comment: Ah, got it; thanks, @SteveChambers!

Answer (score 2):

Since your failed system was on Catalina, which uses the *Read-Only System Volume* scheme with separate `System` and `Data` volumes, it sounds like you backed up only the `System` volume. The `/Users` directory, however, is stored in `Data`.

One possibility for why you did this is that the `Data` volume might be corrupted and unmountable and therefore didn’t show up in *Disk Drill*, so the `System` volume was your only obvious choice.

Another possibility is that High Sierra is two major OS releases behind Catalina. In general, it is inadvisable to mount an APFS volume from one OS using an older OS because APFS is a moving target and there are changes and additions to the format & filesystem driver that occur between releases. While unlikely, your wife’s machine may not be able to recognize the `/Data` volume. (It’s also unlikely but possible that mounting it on the old OS could have unintentionally caused damage to the newer format.) I haven’t used *Disk Drill* so it is possible that it *did* image your entire drive and the `Data` volume is still hiding in the .dmg, waiting to be read on a newer OS.

As a general rule, any time disk corruption is suspected, your #1 goal is to minimize disk usage (especially when hosted on the faulty machine) until you’re ready to perform a repair or transfer. Repair is no longer an option since *Disk Utility* couldn’t do it and no other APFS tools are currently available. So you’re left with transfer.

To maximize your chance of transfer, you need to be running at least the same version of OS on the lifeboat unit. You would also ideally be able to remove the physical drive from the target machine and place it in an external enclosure. Even so, your chance of success is slim if the `Data` drive failed to appear. You do need to be able to accept the fact that your data may be gone. (You could take out the SSD and set it aside, waiting for [DiskWarrior 6](https://www.alsoft.com) to come out and give you another chance at recovery.)

In short, try again with a Catalina machine, but minimize how much time the drive is powered on and be ready to call it a day.

Comment: Thank you!!! This ended up being exactly it! Got two USB C-to-A adapters, so I could plug the two drives (original 1 TB SSD and newly-purchased 2 TB backup drive) into my 2018 15" MBP work machine (only USB C on it). And voilà! — there it was, the `Data` volume, with my user folder in plain view! Doing a straight via-Finder copy of `Applications`, `System`, `Users` and `Library` over to the 1 TB drive first. What should I do from there? Use Disk Utility to make an image of the whole drive (saved to backup drive), then restore from the image immediately after formatting the main drive?